# address of deployed RoleManagement contract on Volta

Tags: contract-design

I'm trying to set up my own Origin framework and was wondering if it made sense to reuse the existing `RoleManagement` contract on the volta network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the core Origin developers here.

The `RoleManagement` contract is no longer in use in the latest version of Origin.
Latest versions of Origin manage permissions with the following combination:

- On-chain permissioning: OpenZeppelin `Ownable` contract
- Off-chain permissioning: Role-based permissioned NestJS API endpoints

We're in a constant improvement process, so this might change in the future as better tooling is created.